# How do I query for records that all have the same relationships (MS Access)?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to query for records that share common relationships. In order to avoid gratuitous context, here is a hypothetical example from my favorite old-school Nintendo game:

Consider a table of boxers:

```
tableBoxers
ID  | boxerName
----------------
1   | Little Mac
2   | King Hippo
3   | Von Kaiser
4   | Don Flamenco
5   | Bald Bull
```

Now I have a relationship table that links them together

```
boxingMatches
boxerID1   |  boxerID2
-----------------------
1          |  3
2          |  5
2          |  4
5          |  1
4          |  1
```

Since I don't want to discriminate between ID1 and ID2, I create a query that UNIONs them together:

```
SELECT firstID AS boxerID1, secondID AS boxerID2 FROM
(
  SELECT boxerID1 AS firstID, boxerID2 AS boxerID FROM boxingMatches
  UNION ALL
  SELECT boxerID2 AS firstID, boxerID1 AS secondID FROM boxingMatches
) ORDER  BY firstID, secondID
```

I get:

```
queryBoxingMatches
boxerID1   |  boxerID2
-----------------------
1          |  3
1          |  4
1          |  5
2          |  4
2          |  5
3          |  1
4          |  1
4          |  2
5          |  1
5          |  2
```

Now I have VBA script where a user can select the boxers he's interested in. Let's say he selects Little Mac (1) and King Hippo (2). This gets appended into a temporary table:

```
summaryRequest
boxerID
--------
1
2
```

Using table [summaryRequest] and [queryBoxingMatches], how do I find out whom Little Mac (1) and King Hippo (2) have similarly fought against? The result should be Bald Bull (5) and Don Flamenco (4).

Bear in mind that [summaryRequest] could have 0 or more records. I have considered an INTERSECT, but I'm not sure that's the right function for this. I've tried using COUNT numerous ways, but it gives undesired data when there are multiple relationships (e.g. if Little Mac fought Bald Bull twice and King Hippo only fought him once).

I can't help but feel like the answer is plain and simple and I'm just overthinking it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `COUNT` actually sounds good, what did you try with it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that works like this in MS Access:

```
SELECT boxerID2, COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM queryBoxingMatches
WHERE boxerID1 IN (SELECT boxerID FROM summaryRequest)
GROUP BY boxerID2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT boxerID1) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT boxerID) 
                                   FROM summaryRequest)
```

Comment: So since the outer query has an aggregate function, I tried it with GROUP BY boxerID2.

Comment: But I still run into the same problem. If Little Mac fights Bald Bull twice, then boxerID 5 appears twice for Little Mac and if King Hippo fights Bald Bull once, then it appears once for King Hippo (3 times total in [queryBoxingMatches]). And there's only 2 boxers (Little Mac and King Hippo) in [summaryRequest]; 3 <> 2. The net result is that Bald Bull ceases to appear in this scenario. If I delete one of the duplicate fights between Little Mac and Bald Bull, then 2 = 2 and it appears.

Comment: At least you were able to execute it by the sound of it. I have updated the answer with `distinct` clause. hope it works in MA Access.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found the answer:

```
SELECT boxerID2 FROM
(
  SELECT boxerID2, COUNT(boxerID2) AS getCount FROM queryBoxingMatches
  WHERE boxerID1 IN (SELECT ID FROM summaryRequest)
  GROUP BY boxerID2
)
WHERE getCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM summaryRequest)
```

It's a play off of COUNT(), which I don't like because COUNT() doesn't guarantee a full-fledged relationship--just a pattern.

Comment: Doh. As soon as I added two duplicate records (e.g. Little Mac vs Bald Bull twice), it throws off the count and filters out Bald Bull completely.

Comment: Okay, I changed the last line to "WHERE VAL(getCount) >= ...". That seemed to resolve the problem (for now). I have a feeling an inconsistency will result down the road, but I suppose this will do.